# a generics method how to invoke another Generics method

Tags: java

I have two generics methods like:

```
<T extends MyClass> T methodA(Class<T> clazz){
...
methodB(clazz);//it is wrong
}

<T extends MyClass> T methodB(Class<T> clazz){
...
}
```

and I want invoke `methodB` in `methodA`, but it does not work. Is there anything I missed?

Comment: can you provide the actual code?

Comment: and the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the return statement. You declared the method returns a object of type T extending class MyClass. But, you have not returned it.

The following code block works for me.

```
public class CodePlay {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CodePlay cp = new CodePlay();
        System.out.println(cp.methodA(null));
    }

    public <T extends MyClass> T methodA(Class<T> clazz){
        // do stuff
        return methodB(clazz);
    }

    public <T extends MyClass> T methodB(Class<T> clazz) {
        // do stuff
        return null;
        // return actual value
    }

}

class MyClass {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: yes,i have found it coused by different return statement,but show param type wrong.

Comment: @西门吹雪 I didn't faced any such issue. Can you paste the actual code?

Comment: like this: `<T extends ClassA> T methodA(Class<T> clazz){
...
return methodB(clazz);//it is wrong ,show the param(clazz) type wrong
}

<T extends ClassB> T methodB(Class<T> clazz){
...
}`

Comment: @西门吹雪 the problem here is there is not relationship between `ClassA` and `ClassB`. If you modify your code like, `class ClassA extends ClassB`, your error will be gone. But, I'm not sure how it will affect your logic.